# how do i get the big facebook image?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been using this approach to get the facebook big profile image

```
http://graph.facebook.com/<FBUID>/picture?type=large
```

but it redirects to another url. Is there a way to get the final url, because in an image tag it take a bit to load them all

```
<img width="46" height="46" src="http://graph.facebook.com/7715177/picture?type=large">
```

I am using php facebook

here is some of my php

```
//Facebook
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $config->get('fb_api_id'),
  'secret' => $config->get('fb_api_secret'),
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
    if ($user) {
      try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;

        }
    }
```

any ideas on how to get the final url after the redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using CURL with the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION set to true on

```
http://graph.facebook.com/<FBUID>/picture?type=large
```

?

Comment: that is one approach, i can try that. I was hoping for a way to get that value returned from some sort of facebook api call